# C#: Using reflection to get access to all fields within a class, returns error

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

can anyone help me?

I have some reflection code that i have written and it seems to work well but it gives me an error when trying to pass in "this" to the GetValue.

I am a little stuck, i think the problem is that i am running the reflection code in frmMain adn the AbCCompany is defined in another project but i have a reference.

I get the error

> Field 'AbcCompany' defined on type 'MyApp.Companies.Config' is not a
>   field on the target object which is of type 'MyApp.frmMain'.

Here is the code..

```
        var companies = MyIems.Companies.GetType().GetFields();


        foreach (var list in companies )
        {

            List<CompanyBase> thisCompanyCollection = (List<CompanyBase>)list.GetValue(this);
            foreach (var company in thisCompanyCollection )
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
```

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that Inside "Companies" is lots of List where xxx is a class.. all classes inherit from CompanyBase.  i.e AbcCompany

Comment: please show the fields of `MyItems.Companies` and the declaration of `CompanyBase`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of passing in `this` to `GetValue` you need to pass an instance of `MyApp.Companies.Config`.

If you look at [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue.aspx), you can see that the exception your getting is because the `obj` parameter isn't of the type (or inherits from it) that the current field is declared on.

Assuming that `MyApp.Companies.Config` has a parameterless constructor, the following should work:

```
var type = MyItems.Companies.GetType();

var instance = type.GetConstructor(System.Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(null);

foreach(var list in type.GetFields())
{
    List<CompanyBase> thisCompanyCollection = (List<CompanyBase>)list.GetValue(instance);
    foreach(var company in thisCompanyCollection)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(company);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code sample provided says `MyItems.Companies.GetType()`, `GetType` is an instance method not a static method so `Companies` is a variable, `MyItems` possibly is as well. The exception message states the type name is `MyApp.Companies.Config` which is what `MyItems.Companies` is an instance of.