# How to pass the current instance to FieldInfo.GetValue inside the instance?

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, system.reflection

I'm making an abstract class that I need to validate fields in it's descendants. All the validated fields are marked by an attribute and are suppose to be checked for nulls or empty. To do that I get all the fields in the class:

```
var fields = this.GetType().GetFields().Where(field => Attribute.IsDefined(field, typeof(MyAttribute))).ToList();
```

And then, for every FieldInfo I try to do this:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(field.GetValue(this).ToString()))
{
    // write down the name of the field
}
```

I get a **System.NullReferenceException: object reference not set to an instance of an object**.

I know [I am suppose to pass the instance of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110521/c-using-reflection-to-get-access-to-all-fields-within-a-class-returns-error) to the GetValue method. But how can I pass the current instance (the one that's launching the logic)?

Or: Is there an other way of getting the field's value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Lucas says, the problem will be calling `ToString()` when you shouldn't. Presumably your attribute should only be applied to string fields anyway, so the simplest approach is just to cast the result to `string`. If that cast fails, it indicates a bigger bug (the attribute being applied incorrectly).

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string) field.GetValue(this)))
```

Comment: Although Lucas' answer was also working I went for this one because of code ammount. Thanks, Jon :-)

Answer (score 2):

The `GetValue` call is fine. The problem lies in the return value on which you're calling `ToString`.

If `GetValue` returns `null`, then `ToString` will be called on this `null` value, and this will throw the `NullReferenceException`.

Do something like this instead:

```
var value = field.GetValue(this);
if (value == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
{
    // write down the name of the field
}
```